# Laptop Ultrawide monitor compatibility

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, compatibility, widescreen

I have an MSI GF63 8RD, and I am trying to use my Acer ED347CKR ultrawide monitor with it, but the resolution of the laptop will only go to 2560x1440, but I need it to go to 3440x1440. Am I missing something because it says it can support up to 4k at 30Hz, but this is not a 4k monitor, so I thought it would support it. Am I misinterpreting what that means, or can the laptop's hardware just not support that high of a resolution?

[Monitor Specs](https://www.newegg.com/black-acer-ed7-series-ed347ckr-bmidphzx-34/p/N82E16824011196#)

[Laptop Specs](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GF63-8RX/Specification)

Answer (score 1):

No - I saw a couple of references but the one below was best. Most laptop video drivers have limits with how they can present.

[GeForce 3440x1040 resolution](https://www.quora.com/Will-a-GeForce-GTX-1050-Card-run-a-3440x1440-100Hz-Monitor)

Will a GeForce GTX 1050 Card run a 3440x1440 100Hz Monitor?

> Nope, the GTX 1070 was the 1440p choice and that was on normal
> monitors not ultrawides, The 1050 is a budget range GPU and buying it
> now is kind of unjustified because the newer GTX 16 series is a better
> budget choice.
>
> But for your case anything below a RTX 2060 (the equivalent of the
> 1080) is not going to run in a way that I personally would be happy
> with.